# Running a method before pressing a button, like a document.ready function

Tags: java, android, jquery, android-studio, onload-event

Is there in java something like the `$(document).ready(function()`?

When my app runs, the score that is saved using shared preferences refreshes only after i press the "check it" button, and I'd need to do that before everything else, just after the app loads. 
What should I do ?

[image: ss]
[image: ss-after]

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
```

Please read up on [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

[image]